# python 2 stdin can't read individual lines

Tags: python, io, buffer, stdin, python-2.x

I have the following very simple-looking code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print("hello!")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

When I run it, I expect to type in a line and then immediately see `hello!` printed out after it, after which I can type in another line.

When I run it with `py -3` I get expected results:

```
py -3 test.py
asdf
hello!
asdf
hello!
asdf
hello!
^C
```

When I run it with `py -2`, it won't print `hello!` unless I send ctrl-Z:

```
py -2 test.py
asdf
asdf
asdf
^Z
hello!
hello!
hello!
asdf
^Z
hello!
^Z
```

I ran this test on Windows with Python 2.7.12 and on Linux (using ctrl-D instead of ctrl-Z) with Python 2.6.6.

How can I get the Python 2 behavior to match that of Python3?

#### EDIT:

Working Python 3 example on repl.it: https://repl.it/Cs6n/0

Broken Python 2 example on repl.it: https://repl.it/Cs7C/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to your question is here [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering). (4th comment of accepted answer). Your working code should be like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    print("hello!")
```

Works perfect in python 2.7.11

**EDIT**:
last line `sys.stdout.flush()` has been removed. There is no need to use it in this situation.

Comment: Thank you! That was a very vexing problem. Also, there's an official mention of it is in the documentation on the `-u` command line switch.

Comment: If output buffering is disabled, the last line does not do anything, does it?

Comment: This snippet of code works well without last line. No need to use sys.stdout.flush() in this situation, because output buffering is disabled.  Thank's for remark, @guidot.